# Android 12 (Pixel 5) Can I have old-style quick settings panel back somehow?

Tags: android-12, quick-settings

With the Android 12 upgrade, this settings menu became enormously large and a huge waste of space. I mean it is highlighted when it is turned on, nevertheless many of the buttons/switches have "On" or "Off" as an additional written text. Besides this, next to the icon which is commonly used they now waste space writing a pointless explanation like "Bluetooth". By this, about 3 times the screen space is needed per option, which results in less buttons shown on more screen space. Is there a way to have the much better Android 11 design without downgrading and the resulting security issues?

Thanks

Remark: there is no google-pixel-5  Tag available and I cannot create it.